# Why was my flag rejected?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Why was my flag on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195088/how-to-facilitate-meetings-events-with-participant-registration-agenda-and-do) rejected?

It somehow confuses me, because I'd say this question is literally about:

> Implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which
>   just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is
>   provided

So it doesn't fit the scope of this site? Or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was automatically declined because, in the review queue, the question got 3 votes to keep it open, and 2 to close it.

I would agree that is off-topic, since it makes just a list of features they want, and adds a link to a site that is not even made with Drupal.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @kiamlaluno. I'll keep flagging similar questions in the future. (I already thought I was doing to wrong.)