# Improve the quality of reviews?

Tags: discussion, support, review-page

While discovering my bugreport: [Less privileged users can see reviews of other users](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/less-privileged-users-can-see-reviews-of-other-users) I've found a quite some posts getting marked as OK while they were actually a question posted as an answer (or commentary). Admitting that most of these posts were formatted pretty nice and were clear, the left top clearly stated that this was posted as an answer, and as such it is a post that should have been marked for deletion.

I unfortunately did not keep track of these posts, but I've seen more then one of these situations in the past weeks and therefor would like to bring it up.

One example I can quickly find (I did not use above method on it) is [Owl Carousel 2 switches to default position after Ajax call](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199072/owl-carousel-2-switches-to-default-position-after-ajax-call/199159#199159) which I have flagged `not an answer`, and now in my flag list is marked as `disputed`, so I suppose some people marked this as OK, while it is commentary. 
I also posted [Why was my flag rejected?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/why-was-my-flag-rejected) last month here on meta for a similar situation.

I really wonder why some other community members are not properly reviewing, is it haste, lack of interest, the medals, or perhaps is (some step of) the review process unclear?

Can we

- Somehow make the type of post (question, answer) even more visible?
- Enable the 'review test' (SO used to have this, so I suppose we have it too) where sometimes an already reviewed post is added to the queue to test the reviewer? (and do we want to be like that?)
- Train the reviewers to better look at the post and the surrounding context (original question)
- Do anything else to improve this?

Or is this not a problem at all and is it 'normal' in such a big systems that happens every n-th post and should I not worry about it?