# Less privileged users can see reviews of other users

Tags: bug, review-page

This bug was postes as a remark in [Improve the quality of reviews?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/improve-the-quality-of-reviews) but per advise of kiamlaluno it is now a separate topic.

If I review a post and choose my action, I get another post until my queue is empty. Then if I start using the browsers back button I can see the posts again including my own, and reviews of others. I guess that is supposed to be the 10k rep option to review reviews even though I just managed to get 3k together.

Here is a screenshot of what I can see:

[image: Screendump]

I tried this in several review queues and for some I only see my own name (but this could be I was the first to review). So I am not really sure if it happens in al queues, but at least the Low quality posts has this.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact you see the name of other users in that screenshot? A developer will answer about that being the expected behavior, or not. I will just say that 10K users can see all the reviews done, including the ones to which they didn't participate, in a page listing all of them. You can see the decisions taken by other users in the reviews you participated.

Comment: I mean that I can see the names of the users and what button they clicked (the above screenshot). There are no links to special areas where I can see a list of all reviews, and there no other way to reach this page other then using the back button. But I assumed that I should not even be able to see this. I never tried to manually alter the URL or if I can see more content.